# Does this logic belong in my service or component? Angular 2+

Tags: observable, angular-services

I'm getting a bunch of customer data from an api and i am wanting to cache it in my service so different components can access functions that return different queries from the data without making multiple http requests as the data is only updated monthly. Something like this.

```
data;

getData() {
  if (this.data)
    return Observable.of(this.data);

  return this.http.get(***********)
    .map(response => {
      this.accounts = response;
      return this.accounts;
    });
```

Then I have functions **in the service** that components can call to get particular data, in the right shape for displaying in tables etc

```
getDataForSomethingById(id) {
  return this.getData()
    .map(result => {
      //get the data into the right shape
  );
```

And in the component...

```
this.dataService.getDataForSomethingById(1)
  .subscribe(result => this.tableData = result);
```

The issue is a component might call many of these functions on initialization resulting in multiple http calls (only the first time as they all subscribe before the response is recieved). 
My question is, am I going about this the right way? Is the service the correct place for this logic or should this logic be in my component eg.

```
this.dataService.getData()
  .subscribe(result => {
    this.tableData = this.processTable(result);
    this.someListData = this.getListData(result);
```

Or can I somehow do something like this in the service

```
//Initialize this as an observable the the functions can wait until it loads?
data;

// call this on login to get the data
getData() {
  if (this.data)
    return Observable.of(this.data);

  return this.http.get(***********)
    .map(response => {
      this.accounts = response;
      return this.accounts;
    });

getDataForSomethingById(id) {
 //wait for the data to load
 //process the data
 //return it to the component
}
```

Just from thinking about this as I write, I'm leaning towards the component displaying the data should be responsible for getting it in the right shape and the service should only be getting/caching the raw data?

Comment: I think you are right. But don't make all components too smart. It is better to have a few smart components that know how to get data from services and all their children (dummy components) will be populated with data by its parent. Also I would recommend to learn **ngrx** as a way to manage state in ng-app.

Answer (score 0):

It depends for example you cand use your service to query the api and then cache the data what I would do also in the service is to map the data in a standard format for my app, if a component needs this data it can request it in that format and then it can map it in a custom format for the view.